# I am trying to fetch Account details with the text provided in lightning input lwc

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, dynamic-soql, lightninginput

I am trying to fetch the Account Name and Id while entering the text on ligtning input but I am not able to fetch the data from apex here is my code.Pleas help

```html
<!-- mySearchListDemo.html -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="My Search List Demo">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-input
                label="Search Result"
                value={searchTerm}
                onchange={handleChange}
            ></lightning-input>
        </div>

        <template if:true={searchData}>
            <ul>
                <template for:each={searchData} for:item="record">
                    <li key={record.Id}>{record.Name}</li>
                </template>
            </ul>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```js
import { LightningElement, track, api } from 'lwc';
import getRealtedSearch from '@salesforce/apex/RelatedSearchController.getRealtedSearch';

export default class SearchResulltDemo extends LightningElement {

    @api searchTerm = '';
    @track searchData;

    handleChange(event) {
        this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
    }

    handleSearch() {
        getRealtedSearch({ searchTerm: this.searchTerm })
            .then(result => {
                this.searchData = result;
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            });
    }
}
```

```java
public class RelatedSearchController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Sobject> getRealtedSearch(string searchTerm){
        
        String query = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE \'%' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(searchTerm) + '%\' LIMIT 5';

        return DataBase.query(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `<template if:true={searchData}>` thing where the left side of the expression isn't a boolean a pattern in Javscript (i.e. does JS treat it as truthy/falsy where populated = truthy?).

Comment: On a separate note, you never call `handleSearch()`. That's likely the largest factor here.

Answer (score 0):

Without a button to trigger the search, you need to make the searchTerm reactive:
So instead of

```
 getRealtedSearch({ searchTerm: this.searchTerm })
```

you would use :

```
 getRealtedSearch({ searchTerm: '$searchTerm' })
```

Note = anytime searchTerm is changed, it will trigger the getRealtedSearch. So you might want to add a delay in the event handler to stop it executing a search until the user has stopped typing.

Also - not sure why searchTerm is annotated by @api unless you are planning to pass in a value? But if so, you should separate that value from the reactive value, and just set it via a setter.

Answer (score 0):

this is because, when the input change, meaning when user type in something, you are handling the change, but you are not calling the handleSearch() method at all when the input change.

To achieve your desired outcome one easy fix you can make is by adding the handleSearch() method to be called in your handleChange() method. (See code below)

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
    this.handleSearch();
}
```

However, this is not really recommended, because, every-time the input change, you are executing the Apex call.

This is because, you only want to start calling the Apex once the user has finished typing. The code given above, will execute the apex for every single word they are typing, because every change will trigger handleChange() method  which will call handleSearch() method.

For example, if I am typing "Apple" into the input box, I will call the Apex 5 times. One for A, second for AP, third for APP, forth for APPL and last one for APPLE. (as you are typing the searchTerm becomes, A, AP, APP, APPL, APPLE)

As you can see this is not what we want, instead, we want to call the Apex for the keyword Apple

It is recommended to use something call "[debouncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988682/debounce-in-javascript)".

//code credit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75988682/debounce-in-javascript)

```
debounce(callback, delay) {
  let timer;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer)
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      callback();
    }, delay)
  }
}

handleChange(event) {
    this.searchTerm = event.target.value;
    debounce(this.handleSearch(), 500);
}
```

This code above, will not call the Apex method until a user has stopped typing for 500 milliseconds. Of course, you can change the delay to longer/shorter time as you prefer.